# How I fix my character into center of camera with unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, avatar

I need a solution for my problem, please.
I make a character in unity 3d base on AR, the problem is when I build the project in my android phone I can found the character or I should to turn a camera for search where is he.
I need to make this object into the center of my camera how can I do this, please ...

Answer (score 0):

Just re-read your question, AR skimed over that at first ... so you dont want to move the camera rather you want to move the object.

To find the middle of the screen in world space is what you asking for.

```
Camera.current.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f, 100));
```

Use your camera to find a point in the world that is in the middle of your view. You have several options, ViewportToWorldPoint for example as shown above. ViewPort calls 0.5,0.5 the middle of the screen, Z is the distance from the Camera origin point.

You could alternativly cast a ray from your camera center screen and find a point on the ground to put your character at ... would need to know more about your wourld set up to help further.

My old answer is how to move a camera ... I will leave it case its useful to you.

[Edit Old Answer]

The other answer will work and is nice and light but has its limitations as your project advances.

I recomend Cinemachine for camera work, in this case a simple Cinemachine virtual camera setting its 'Look At' and optionaly its 'Follow' is what you want.

Cinemachine works with the concept of 'virtual cameras' these are just light easy to use behvaiours that discribe how to 'frame' a shot e.g. what to look at, how to move, etc.
You real camera will get a Cinemachine 'brain' which simply listens to these virtual cameras and sorts out what to do to the real camera to make it happen. Getting to terms with this system will greatly improve your camera work and masivly simplify it.

Things like simply attaching the camera to the player object and similar work but have big limitations that end up biting you in the backside eventually.
Alternativly you can write a script to transform the camera based on your own custom logic the draw back here is the 'ball of code' problem ... that is at first the logic is simple but as you want more and more specific shots framed up it gets to being a spegettie monster quickly.

Comment: Also, the Cinemachine from Unity learn site has been removed.